# js selector that insertes a ruby partial inside a newly created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I has number fields and associated empty divs. I can a code that does this: when you increase or decrease the number inside the number fields, and a new div insertsAfter the empty div. 1 in number field 1 new div, 2 in number field 1 new div 2 total divs, 3 in number field 1 new div 3 total divs. and so on.

Right now my code is creating a new empty div with out anything in it. But what I want is for the new div to be created with a ruby partial inside the new div.

here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/39/

This is what I have tried in my js.erb file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product-quantity').each(function() {
        $(this).data('val', this.value);
    }).on('change', function () {
            var val = $(this).val(),
                    old = $(this).data('val'),
                    ele = $(this).closest('[id^="product"]').find
                    ('[data-size="'+this.name+'"]'),
                    inc = val >= old;

            if (inc) {
                $('<div/>', {
                    'class': 'name-number-field', 'text':'<%= render :partial => 
                 'name_number_field', :locals => {:product => product, :size => size} %>'
                }).insertAfter(ele);
            }else {
                $('div.name-number-field', ele.parent()).last().remove();
            }

            $(this).data('val', this.value);
        });
});
```

Comment: Let jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how either but I have an idea
the gem 'cocoon' does exactly what you want (render a partial using JS) but it requires association on the models 
Assuming you have no model association, you just want to insert partials, I would suggest to look into cocoon's implementation for idea and approach

> https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/lib/cocoon/view_helpers.rb
>   https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/cocoon.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your js.erb file:

```
$('#yourDiv').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "name_number_field", :locals => { :product => product, :size => size } )%>');
```